# d.ts for css-module can't be generated with typings-for-css-modules-loader

Tags: typescript, webpack, css-modules

I'm trying to use CSS module with Typescript.

I tried with this configuration.

**Webpack config**

```js
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
    entry: "./client/index.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json", ".css"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'typings-for-css-modules?modules' },
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader", options: {
                    configFile: __dirname + "/tsconfig.client.json"
                }
            },

            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

};
```

I want to use CSS module with style codes written in Stylus. Therefore, I can't use typescript language service for this purpose.

I don't mind not to use this webpack plugin. If there are alternative solution, welcome to comment. I want to know best practice around this!

---

**Other files**

There are `./client/index.tsx` and `./client/test.css` with this code.

`./client/index.tsx`

```ts
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as CSS from "./test.css";

class ControlPanelRoot extends React.Component<any, any> {
    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <img src="../public/logo.png" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`./client/test.css`

```css
.aa{
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
}

.bb{
    display: inline;
}
```

But there was no definition file generated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to use those classes defined in .css in your .jsx else they don't generate
`you need to use the imported styles in your code. If you just import them but not use them in the code they will be ignored.`

https://github.com/Jimdo/typings-for-css-modules-loader/issues/27

Answer (score 0):

try out this webpack loader: [react-css-component loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rcc-loader).

see an example with nextjs below:

```
const nextConfig = {
webpack: (config, { dev, isServer }) => {
    const rccLoaderRule = {
      test: /\.module\.scss$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'rcc-loader',
          options: {
            enabled: !!dev && isServer,
            exportStyleOnly: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }

    config.module.rules = config.module.rules ?? []
    config.module.rules.push(rccLoaderRule)

    return config
  }
}
```